# Cuando usar sentencias preparadas o PDO::exec

Tags: php7, php5

Hola a todos tengo la duda de si se debe de usar las sentencias preparadas de PHP o los métodos PDO::exec y PDO::query. La verdad que por constumbre siempre uso las sentencias preparadas para todo. Según mis conocimientos estas se usan para evitar los ataques de inyección. Pero una vez se trabaja internamente en la página, osea ya se han recogido los datos de los formularios, por ejemplo el nombre de usuario,contraseña etc a través de sentencias preparadas ya se puede trabajar de manera segura con PDO::exec.

Tiene sus ventajas he comparado una select con sentencia prepara y otra con PDO::exec y esta última es mucho más rápida además de devolver el número de filas afectadas, cosa que con las sentencias toca usar el método 'rowCount' para estar seguro de que ha hecho el insert o delete.

Hola @A.Cedano no pude responderte ayer por que tengo prohibido usar el ordenador los domingos no se si me entiendes... . Creo haberlo comprendido. Este es un ejemplo de sentencia que se ejecuta en bucle donde según tú explicación es conveniente utilizar las sentencias preparadas:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
                
                if($nuevasPalabras[$i] == null){$nuevasPalabras[$i] = "";} //Nos aseguramos 4 palabras      
                    
                    $stm = " UPDATE ".TBL_PBS_QUERIDAS. " SET palabrasBuscadas = :palabrasBuscadas WHERE idPbsBuscada = :idPbsBuscada and idPostQueridas = :idPostQueridas;";
                            //echo $stm;
                    $stm = $con->prepare($stm);
                    $stm->bindValue(":idPostQueridas", $idPostPa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stm->bindValue(":palabrasBuscadas", $nuevasPalabras[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stm->bindValue(":idPbsBuscada", $buscadas[$i]['idPbsBuscada'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stm->execute();
                     
                       
                        //$actualizo = $stm->rowCount();
                            
            }
```

Pero yo también las usaba en este tipo de métodos:

```
 $sqlValiEmail = "Update ".TBL_USUARIO. " SET bloqueado = :bloqueado WHERE  idUsuario = :idUsuario";
     $stmValiEmail = $con->prepare($sqlValiEmail);
     $stmValiEmail->bindValue(":bloqueado", DESBLOQUEO_EMAIL, PDO::PARAM_STMT);
     $stmValiEmail->bindValue(":idUsuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
     $stmValiEmail->execute();
    
     $count = $stmValiEmail->rowCount();
```

Como se ve en cada sentencia tenía que llamar a rowCount para saber que había tenido éxito. Como comente arriba además es un poco más lenta que usar PDO::exec(). Ahorra este tipo de métodos los creare de esta manera:

```
 $con = Conne::connect(); 


     $sqlValiEmail = "Update ".TBL_USUARIO. " SET bloqueado = ".DESBLOQUEO_EMAIL." WHERE  idUsuario = $id;";
    
     $count = $con->exec($sqlValiEmail);
     
      if($count === 0){throw new Exception("Error al activar la cuenta desde el email",0);}
   
     if($count === 1){
         
        //eliminarTablaDesbloquear($id);
        //mandarEmails::mandarEmailWelcome($nick);
        //header(MOSTRAR_PAGINA_INDEX);
     }

} catch (Exception $ex) {
  
    $_SESSION['emailNoActivado'] = $nick. " y su id es: $id";//se elimina en metodosInfoExcepcione
    $excepciones = new MisExcepcionesUsuario(CONST_ERROR_BBDD_ACTIVAR_CUENTA_EMAIL[1],CONST_ERROR_BBDD_ACTIVAR_CUENTA_EMAIL[0],$ex);
    $excepciones->redirigirPorErrorSistemaUsuario("desbloquearUsuario",true);
```

Funciona más rápido y no tienes que llamar a rowCount. Gracias

Comment: Usar sentencias preparadas es más eficaz en contextos repetitivos (por ejemplo si debes volver a ejecutar nuevas consultas con nuevos datos), porque al preparar la sentencia el SGBD traza el plan de ejecución de esa consulta una sola vez, lo que hace que las consultas subsiguientes sean más rápidas. En un ejemplo de la vida real, es como ir a un sitio, la primera vez tardas más porque no sabes a dónde vas, pero las veces siguientes vas más rápido porque ya conoces el camino.

Comment: La misma documentación sugiere considerar `PDO::query()` para consultas de una vez, pero se sugiere escapar datos internos con `PDO::quote()`, pero si se usa para construir sentencias recomiendan `PDO::prepare()`; lo cual te deja montado en un carrusel para que te bajes donde te convenga.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por responder. Pero tengo una duda a: "Usar sentencias preparadas es más eficaz en contextos repetitivos". ¿Que es repetitivos? Por ejemplo en una web sería una sentencia que comprobase usuario y contraseña. Ese concepto de repetitivo ya lo leí en la documentación de PHP pero nunca me quedo claro. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo de una sentencia que fuera repetitiva y otra que no lo fuera?. Para mi todas se repiten, unas más y otras menos. Por ejemplo modificar la cuenta de un usuario es menos repetitiva que comprobar usuario y contraseña para hace login.

Comment: Imagina que necesitas ejecutar la sentencia varias veces, pero con datos distintos cada vez, es algo habitual en un contexto de bucle por ejemplo. O supongamos una transacción donde se procesan datos por lotes. O cualquier otro contexto en el que necesites ejecutar la misma consulta más de una vez.